# Nokogumbo 1.4.7 does not recognize development tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason, when I run 'bundle install' in my root directory, every gem succeeds in installing - except for Nokogumbo-1.4.7. Here is the error I receive:

```
C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for xmlNewDoc() in -lxml2... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in `try_link0'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `try_link'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:714:in `try_func'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:944:in `block in have_library'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:889:in `block in checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:888:in `checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:939:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

mkmf.log shows the following:

```
"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -std=c99 conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:

/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

When I first got this error, I reinstalled and tested the DevKit by following the instructions outlined on [its GitHub](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit%20%22its%20Github), tried again, and received the same error.

I did further research, and found someone who had the same issue as I did, but with an earlier version of Nokogumbo. The issue can be found [here](https://github.com/rubys/nokogumbo/issues/9). I followed the "hacky workaround" described in the comments of this issue, but it did not work for me.

I've had trouble finding any other support for this gem, as the only issues I can find are only related to Nokogiri, which I've had no trouble installing.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the next steps I should take?

Thanks in advance!

Additional information:
  - Ruby on Rails V 4.2.6
  - Ruby V 2.0.0

Comment: Please post the related part of `mkmf.log`.

Comment: why are you using 'nokogumbo' instead of nokogiri? It seems unnecessary to wrap one HTML parser in another.

Comment: It wasn't my choice to use the gem. I'm trying to use Community Engine, which requires Nokogumbo for some reason. mkmf.log should be up now.